# Два домена SEO оптимизация

Tags: seo

У меня такая ситуация: есть два домена domen.ru и domen.ua. Оба сайта одинаковы, но для domen.ua были заменены картинки на сайте. То есть для Украины актуален domen.ua. Как в таком случая будет лучше поступить с оптимизацией без ущерба основного domen.ru.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем вопросе непонятна фраза "Оба сайта одинаковы". Означает ли это что вы используете один и тот же фреймворк? Или это означает что содержание вебсайтов дублировано?

В первом случае использование одного и того же фреймворка не имеет значения для поисковой оптимизации. Это дело веб-мастера, но не поисковиков.

Однако, в случае дублированного содержания, все усложняется. Вы говорите нам, что вы заменили картинки на веб-сайте для Украины. Однако при дублированном тексте поисковикам будет трудно определить какой из двух веб-сайтов является релевантным для поискового запроса связанного с темой обоих ваших веб-сайтов.

Лучшее решение для этой ситуации есть создание уникального содержания для Украины. Украинцы и русские есть разные национальности и имеют различный менталитет и интересы. Определите **[уникальное торговое предложение](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)** для темы вашего веб-сайта, которая может интересовать украинцев и на основе этого создайте содержание для Украины.

Альтернативное решение. Установите **[каноническую мета ссылку](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066)** на каждой веб-страницы с дублированным содержанием одного из двух веб-сайтов - Гугл называет это "нормализацией". Поисковики будут переходить по этой мета ссылке на каноническую версию. Однако весь сок достанется также для канонической версии. В этом случае не каноническая версия просто не будет иметь смысла.

Для понимания проверьте руководство Гугл **[Страницы с идентичным контентом](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359)**.

Comment: Контент одинаковый на сайтах, отличается немного. Думаю попробовать привязать каждый из доменов к региону.

Comment: Надеюсь никаких санкций от поисковиков не получим.

Comment: Чтобы гарантировать ваш веб-сайт от санкций надо следовать политике и всем руководствам поисковиков. Кроме санкций есть также алгоритмический штраф, понижающий ранг вебсайта в поиске. Например для Гугл может быть важным содержание высокого уровня надежность и для всех важна техническая оптимизация.

Comment: Ага. Почитал их доки. Пришел к выводу, что надо установить hreflang на обоих сайтах. Так и сделал.

Answer (score 0):

Регион можно задать на домены через Google Search Console в старом интерфейсе:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/3506535?hl=ru

В Яндекс.Вебмастере можно тоже задать отдельный регион на домен:
https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/site-geography/site-region.html